# I want to display my string in a text text box but it is not doing this

Tags: javascript, html, forms, textbox

I have a javascript function below:

```
var alphabet = [ "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z" ];  

function generateRandomString(strLength) {     
    var output = "";     
    for (var i = 0; i < strLength; i++) {         
        var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * alphabet.length);         
        output += alphabet[randomIndex];     }     
        return output; }  

        function getSession() {     
            var randomDiv = document.getElementById("randomStrings");     
            newText = generateRandomString(3);     
            randomDiv.innerHTML = newText; 
            }
```

What this function does is retrieve any of the letters 3 times and display it e.g. AGH, TRY, MNK etc.

This is displayed in a paragraph like below:

```
<p id="randomStrings"></p>
```

The above code does actually successfully display the code on screen. But because I want to post this data into another page I think it is best to not use `<p>` tag to display random strings but instead use a test box to display it. Problem is that if I do this it does not display the randomString in the text box. Why is randomString not displaying on screen in the text box?

Below is form code:

```
 <form action="QandATable.php" method="post" id="sessionForm">
          <table>
          <tr>
          <th>1: </th>
          <td><input id="sessionBtn" type="button" value="Get Session ID" name="sessionid" onClick="getSession()" /></td>   <!-- Get Session ID here-->
          <td><input type="text" id="randomStrings" name="random" readonly="readonly"/></td>
          </tr>
          </table>
</form>
```

Comment: You have to set the value for an input, not the innertHTML

Comment: i dont understand, how anything will be shown in teztbox, let alone random string. it dont have any value specified.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to generate that server side ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the **value** property instead of **innerHTML**.

```
 function getSession() {     
    var randomDiv = document.getElementById("randomStrings");     
    newText = generateRandomString(3);     
    randomDiv.value = newText; 
 }
```